# Links in injected float div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I inject html to div on the page (contains float div)

```
var text = "some text<div style='float:rigth'><a href='#'>foo</a></div>"
$("#taget").html(text);
```

After that users of Google Chrome and Safari cannot click at link "foo"

Comment: Did you mean $("#taget").html(text) ?

Comment: yes ^_^ just wrote from my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/axaje

works fine for me.

Comment: finaly I found a blue link on black background :)
It's really works in Chrome. Looks like I need to investigate my case more carefully. For now - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use either

```
$("#taget").html(text);
```

Or use

```
document.getElementById("taget").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: sorry guys. I've already use
$("#taget").html(text);
The question is about link in float div. Not about injection of html.

Comment: What do you want the link to do? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I mean that link style is OK but I cannot click on it (even cursor is "arrow" on such link)